# How to call smart contract from html/Javascript

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, interfaces

I want to have an html/Javascript code interact with a smart contract. Can someone  please outline the basic/high level steps? I am seeing too many things spread across the net,  finally confusing.

Comment: For more advanced JavaScript developers, here is a tutorial https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/ - However it assumes you are well versed in JavaScript.

Comment: You could run this example to get an idea about how we develop a dapp https://github.com/bellaj/Ballot-Dapp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be of some help. http://hypernephelist.com/2016/06/21/a-simple-smart-contract-ui-web3.html

There are frameworks that conveniently deal with dependencies, so a lot of us prefer to go that route. A very high-level overview if what's described in the link, is you will need to:

1. load the web3 API
2. get the ABI (a JSON helper that describes the interface to the contract)
3. initialize an instance of the contract at the address where the contract resides using web3.
4. call() (read-only, fast and gas-free, returns value) or sendTransaction() (state-changing, needs mining, costs gas, returns txnHash).
5. you get a callback from step 4. Wait for the transaction to be mined and then get the mined transaction to see the values, if it was a state-changing transaction.

I hope I didn't miss a step. It's high-level. The link above seems to cover the steps described. :-)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I downloaded its source code from its githup repositoty here : https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard However, when I open index.html it looks like different with its output screen shot inserted in http://hypernephelist.com. For compare: https://ibb.co/d2Rjin and https://ibb.co/heLc3n

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [JavaScript Web3 API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API). It has almost everything you need such as connection to your blockchain, creating and deploying a smart contract, interacting with them.

In my opinion, no need to describe an example, the doc speaks by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [Embark](http://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework), the `embark demo` route is a very good way to quickly get started.

Answer (score 0):

I just created [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-nft-tokenuri-bl14wf?file=/src/index.js) that may help others with the setup. It gets the tokenURI of an NFT, but could pretty easily be extended to do other things with smart contracts.

For your convenience, here is the gist of the code:

```js
// Excerpts from https://github.com/theweaver19/checkmynft

import Web3 from "web3";
import { ERC721ABI } from "./ERC721ABI";

const nftAddress = "0x2a46f2ffd99e19a89476e2f62270e0a35bbf0756";
const tokenId = "40913";

const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

const main = async () => {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ERC721ABI, nftAddress);
  const tokenURI = await contract.methods.tokenURI(tokenId).call();
  console.log({ tokenURI });
};

main();
```