# is there any way to save data from sensor on smart contract automatically?

Tags: solidity, raspberry-pi

I want to take the temperature value from one sensor on save it on the contract of manually , i tried to use `node-red` , or `raspberry pi` but i didn't get a good result.

the second question is it expensive to do it like this ? I mean saving data on the contact how much does it cost?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a [transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction)(function call) using [web3 javascript library](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11840/how-to-call-smart-contract-from-html-javascript).

`the second question is it expensive to do it like this ? I mean saving data on the contact how much does it cost?`

It's expensive. so I recommend testing it on private network.

---

If you run ethereum node at `rasberry pi`, it requires 2GB RAM.

and it makes device warm. I recommend running private servers on PC.

Comment: could you please give an example to see how it works

Comment: On the expensive question: It is expensive if you use Ethereum. You may want to consider other blockchains if you have a high transaction volume.